# Edit to Answer Disappeared

Tags: support, answers, edits

I edited this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9269899/346309), which was my own question.  The edit I made disappeared and revision history does not show it was edited by me or pending edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/202650) by Truth and talonmies. You can always view your [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346309/jpm?tab=activity) in your profile to see a list of your suggested edits. It doesn't show which ones were accepted or rejected from that specific page (*disappointed face*) but you can click them to see the edit and the reasons why it was rejected (if it was).

Comment: Well they screwed it up for the next person as the answer has flaws in it it will error out on the setText() due to trying to update the UI thread from another thread.  My edit fixed that issue.

Comment: @JPM: When you're making edits to code, you should include more detail as to why exactly the code provided should *not* be used. Your edit description described what you were doing, but it did not provide any details about the code not working. You have to realize that the people reviewing your edit may not even read the answer or may not be familiar with the subject. All they're seeing is changes to code, which more often that not, is an inappropriate edit.

Comment: Hmm thats kind of disturbing, I only edit things I know about and can confirm.  If someone made changes to code I would make sure its right before I approve or disapprove it.